# How to delete custom log created by Log Analytics Data collector API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-log-analytics

How can i perform delete operation on custom log in azure log analytics ?
ex : DemoExample_CL
[image]

I can delete it when create one in Advanced settings>Data>Custom Logs, but when i use "[Log Analytics Data collector API](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api)", it did not show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, this is currently unsupported.

Similar feedback shown here ->  (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics/suggestions/16434184-delete-custom-logs-sended-by-http-data-collector-a) was shared directly with the responsible Azure feature team. I recommend navigating to the above link and clicking the vote button to raise visibility and priority on this (or) you may raise another feedback which clearly states that you are looking for a feature which helps to 'delete custom log type that is created by Log analytics Data Collector API'.

Just a side note, if you want to delete only content under particular log type then you may try this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/personal-data-mgmt#delete purge API. Also please note that this API must not be treated as general-purpose data delete API, but used for GDPR purposes only.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Really appreciate your help.I guess i gotta wait until it become available

Comment: situation changed you can delete _CL tables from "Custom Logs" tab in Log Analytics Workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it following the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspacepurge/purge

You can click on "Try It", then you will have to login, provide the name of resource group, workstation name and table name and it will do the trick.

Not ideal, but at least it's possible somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the logs by going to the log analytics workspace of the corresponding sentinel instance.

Inside the log analytics workspace there is a "Custom Logs" tab under settings[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG3bR.png)

Click on the three dots of the required custom logs to be deleted.